# how to hide / show menu items dynamically in popup in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a popup menu like this:

```
<a href="#MenuBeobListe" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a ui-btn-icon-notext">Menu</a>
<div data-role="popup" class="popup" id="MenuBeobListe" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Menü:</li>
        <li class="admin"><a class="menu_artengruppen_importieren" href="#">Artengruppen importieren</a></li>
        <li class="admin"><a class="menu_arten_importieren" href="#">Arten importieren</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu_hierarchischer_modus" href="#">hierarchischer Modus</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu_felder_verwalten" href="#">Felder verwalten</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu_beob_exportieren" href="#">Beobachtungen exportieren</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu_einstellungen" href="#">Einstellungen</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu_neu_anmelden" href="#">neu anmelden</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When an admin logs in to my app I want to set additional menu items visible. These items are already included in the html and have class "admin". They are initially hidden like this:

```
.popup .admin {
  display: none;
}
```

After an admin logs in I try to show them like this:

```
$(".popup").find(".admin").css("display", "block");
$(".popup").popup();
```

This doesn't work even though if I run

```
$(".popup").find(".admin").css("display", "block");
```

directly in the browser, the menu-items for admins are shown.

Can you help please?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t7RXa/ perhaps you just have it in the wrong place? You do not need to reinitialize the popup, so leave out the line $(".popup").popup();

Comment: @ezanker: yep. but the setting got set back when changing pages. I had to change the code to run every time a page is shown. Now it works. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @ezanker: thanks for pointing out that initializing is not necessary!

Comment: I guess jquery mobile reapplies css on show-events?